# ReactJs external JavaScript files not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, masonry

I'm using a external JavaScript library called Masonry (Cascading grid layout library) `https://masonry.desandro.com/`.

I have created a demo page using this library and everything seems to work fine, However once i incorporate this library in a React app it doesn't work.

**Scripts**

```
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="../src/assets/js/JQuery/masonry.js"></script> -->
  <script>
    $(window).on('load', function(){
      var $content = $('.content-container').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.masonry',
      percentPosition: true,
      singleMode: true
      });

      $content.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $content.masonry('layout');
      });
      console.log('Works!')
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I have tried two methods, adding an external JavaScript file `masonry.js` and adding the code in a script tag within the index.html page. whenever i use the external JavaScript file it doesn't work at all (the `console.log('Works!')` doesn't even show in the console). But if i use the code within the Script tag in the index.html page the masonry works occasionally if i do a few page refreshes and the `console.log('Works!')` shows up in the console every time.

I'm not sure if its because Reactjs has a different way in adding external JavaScript libraries / files, but i have searched online what is the correct way to set up external JavaScript files in a react app and it came up with multiple methods so i'm kind of confused to witch is the correct / best.

Also i have checked the Network in the browser developer tools and the external library / JS file imports seems to be loading in fine.

Just a note: the `.content-container` child elements change on button clicks in the Reactjs but not in the demo page.

Comment: this doesnt seem very reactive. I would probably say creating a component that would wrap what your trying to do and set the init on componentDidMount would be the right way to do it. 

as far as your error goes... Im assuming since react injects itself to the DOM perhaps the load ends before the inject begins.

either way. what your doing is not really reactive

Comment: @Jony-Y i have tried loading in the scripts on componentDidMount within a wrapper as well but the external JS files are loading into the Network but not working on the page.

Comment: you dont need to load the script, although you can... I meant on componentDidMount run the function... init the masonry function